# Windows 7 C: drive filling up automatically

Tags: windows-7, virus, disk-space

I have around 24 GB of free space, but within ten minutes of starting up the computer this free space starts filling up automatically. This continues until free space is down 0 KB, whereupon it says not enough space to perform any task on the computer.

I don't want to format the PC and I don't have any restore points any clue what should I do? It affects my download as well as internet surfing. I am also using (paid) Avira Antivirus.

Comment: Use [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to find out where all the space is going.

Comment: I agree what Daniel B said. And it could be caused by any virus that fills your entire C drive.

Comment: The file is "user" size: around 18GB .Real size:2.7 GB

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: You need to explore further. The “Users” folder contains your user profile. If you believe you found the problem, provide a screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps there is a file extension that you're not seeing.  To be able to see the file extension, make sure you have done this: in Windows Explorer, do Organize (top left) -> Folder and Search Options -> View -> Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types".